# Using JScrollPane with JGraphX

Tags: java, jscrollpane, jgrapht

I want to create simple graph inside a JScrollPane present in my GUI. I was trying to do so by using the "Hello world" example distributed with JGraphX, the resutlt is as shown below:

```
public class GraphTest{
public GraphTest(FrameWithScrollPane frame)
{

    mxGraph graph = new mxGraph();
    Object parent = graph.getDefaultParent();

    graph.getModel().beginUpdate();
    try
    {
        Object v1 = graph.insertVertex(parent, null, "Hello", 20, 20, 80,
                30);
        Object v2 = graph.insertVertex(parent, null, "World!", 240, 150,
                80, 30);
        graph.insertEdge(parent, null, "Edge", v1, v2);
    }
    finally
    {
        graph.getModel().endUpdate();
    }

    mxGraphComponent graphComponent = new mxGraphComponent(graph);
            frame.setNewPane(new JScrollPane(graphComponent));
}

public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        FrameWithScrollPane frame = new FrameWithScrollPane();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        GraphTest test = new GraphTest(frame);
    }
}
```

Here I was trying to replace already existing JScrollPane with a new one, but I can't get this to work. The only way to insert a graph in a JScrollPane seems to be having a clean JFrame, and then creating a whole new JScrollPane, with graphComponent as a constructor's argument... which is not what I need, already working with a complex GUI modeled with Netbeans GUI Builder. Adding graphComponent to existing JScrollPane also doesn't work.
Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Actually I've foung the answer myself. All I needed to do, is adding graphComponent to scrolledPane viewport.